# Move pointer in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I am trying to figure out how i can let MS Access use a field value that is 3 rows lower.
The data is from an external source which retrieves SNMP data every week. I linked a table in Access to the txt output file.

Here is a sample:

```
| Device  | IP Address | Uptime    | SNMP Custom | 
--------------------------------------------------
| Router  | 192.168..  | 1 day, 1h | IOS version |
```

Now when i want to get more information of the devices, Cisco descided it was needed to add new lines to the output file so now the linked table looks like:

```
| Device   | IP Address | Uptime    | SNMP Custom | SNMP Custom 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Router   | 192.168..  | 1 day, 1h | IOS version |
| Technical Support: sometext
| Copyright (c) sometext
| Compiled | ABCD
```

Now those 4 lines are from 1 device and the ABCD should be in the SNMP Custom 2 field. The exessive rows i can simply delete but i have no idea how to move the ABCD value to the SNMP Custom 2 field.

Can this be done using MS Access(VB?) or classic ASP? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your OP correctly, try try the following in an Access query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET [SNMP Custom 2] = [IP Address], [IP Address] = "" WHERE [Device] = "Compiled"
```

Comment: That almost does everything i wanted, awesome. 
The ABCD is now in the SNMP Custom 2 field but is still in the same row. Is it possible to move it up so it's behind the other data?

Comment: Anything is possible :) Moving the value to another row would be more involved, and you'd need a method of finding the related row.

Comment: For those items it's basicly always those 4 rows that are returned. The bottom 3 are always static with default values (except for the ABCD one). I'll spend some google time to solve the rest but you've helped me a lot so far. Thanks!